# How to check if a AD group is being denied access to a file or a folder

Tags: windows, active-directory

How to check if a particular AD group is being denied access to a particular file or a folder, using bat /powershell 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get-acl` will get the ACEs assigned to an object. You can parse that for what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you know how I could look for a particular string in the list of access being listed ?

Comment: Of course you can.